# Plotting geometric graph with gnuplot from C++

Tags: c++, pipe

I have written a code in C++ that finds the edges of a geometric graph, given the coordinates of the nodes (points that are close enough to each other are connected). I now want to plot the graph, piping the coordinates of the links to Gnuplot. This looks like this:

```
FILE *pipe = popen("gnuplot -persist", "w");
fprintf(pipe, "\n");
fprintf(pipe, "set polar\n");
fprintf(pipe, "plot '-' with linespoints \n");
```

Now every time a link is found (using breadth-first search algorithm), I do

```
fprintf(pipe, "%g %g\n", RC[j].angle,RC[j].radius);
fprintf(pipe, "%g %g\n", RC[start[ptr]].angle,RC[start[ptr]].radius);
fprintf(pipe, "%g %g\n");
```

and when the search algorithm is finished, I end with

```
fprintf(pipe, "e\n");
fflush(pipe);
fclose(pipe);
```

This, however, does not print the geometrical graph I would expect (points that are far removed turn out to be connected). If I write the data to a file using this procedure

```
outfile << RC[j].angle << ", " << RC[j].radius << endl;
outfile << RC[start[ptr]].angle << ", " << RC[start[ptr]].radius << endl;
outfile << " " << endl;
```

I do get the graph I want. What is wrong with the pipe?

Comment: Make your C++ program write to a standard file and give this file to gnuplot; this way you would know if it's a C++ or gnuplot error.

Comment: Followed your advice, via a standard file I get the graph I am looking for. So the error is in the piping algorithm. Post edited.

Comment: May I have feedback on my answer?

Answer (score 0):

From your `std::ostream` and `fprintf` versions, I can tell the difference is obvious: you forgot the comas (,) + empty line in your `fprintf` version:

```
fprintf(pipe, "%g, %g\n", RC[j].angle, RC[j].radius);
fprintf(pipe, "%g, %g\n", RC[start[ptr]].angle, RC[start[ptr]].radius);
fprintf(pipe, " \n");
```

---

As an alternative, I would suggest to use C++ classes instead of old C functions (untested):

```
class Pipe : public std::ofstream // in most cases this is bad, but ok here
{
public:
    Pipe( FILE* pf ) : _pg(pf) {}
    ~Pipe() { pclose(pf); }
    // copy-ctr(), op=(), ...
private:
    FILE _pf;
};

Pipe gnuplot(popen("gnuplot -persist", "w"));
gnuplot << "\n"
        << "set polar\n"
        << "plot '-' with linespoints\n";

for (...)
{
     gnuplot << RC[j].angle << ", " << RC[j].radius << "\n";
     gnuplot << RC[start[ptr]].angle << ", " << RC[start[ptr]].radius << "\n";
     gnuplot << " " << std::endl; 
}
```